# How to set Proxy Auto Config (PAC) file in WSO2 API Manager

Tags: proxy, wso2, auto, apim

I am using WSO2 API Manager

How to set Proxy Auto Config (PAC) file in axi2.xml?

Answer (score 0):

PAC seems to be a client-side JS file which can't be used at server-side. So you can read that file and configure axis2.xml manually.